# Can't connect to PSQL Database on a VM from my Mac

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-fusion, postgresql

Trying to connect to my PSQL database on my CentOS VM from my Mac using pgAdmin3. Getting the following error:

```
Access to database denied
The server doesn't grant access to the database: the server reports 
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.16.30.1", user "gpadmin", database "postgres", SSL off
```

The VM's IP address is 172.16.30.139 and hence I'm using it as a host. I have added the following into my pg_hba.conf file:

```
local all     gpadmin     ident
#host all     gpadmin     127.0.0.1/28      trust
#host all     gpadmin     192.168.249.131/32    trust
local gpperfmon   gpmon                             md5
host     all     all     192.168.2.109   md5
```

Where `192.168.2.109` is my Macs internal IP address.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I also ran a tcpdump and then tried connecting and see the following logs (but I don't know how to read them):

```
11:00:03.740455 IP 172.16.30.1.58043 > 172.16.30.139.postgres: S 3397342885:3397342885(0) win 65535 <mss 1460,nop,wscale 3,nop,nop,timestamp 837321186 0,sackOK,eol>
11:00:03.740500 IP 172.16.30.139.postgres > 172.16.30.1.58043: S 3408844558:3408844558(0) ack 3397342886 win 5792 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 74855527 837321186,nop,wscale 7>
11:00:03.740630 IP 172.16.30.1.58043 > 172.16.30.139.postgres: . ack 1 win 65535 <nop,nop,timestamp 837321186 74855527>
11:00:03.740650 IP 172.16.30.1.58043 > 172.16.30.139.postgres: P 1:9(8) ack 1 win 65535 <nop,nop,timestamp 837321186 74855527>
11:00:03.740660 IP 172.16.30.139.postgres > 172.16.30.1.58043: . ack 9 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 74855527 837321186>
11:00:03.744513 IP 172.16.30.139.postgres > 172.16.30.1.58043: P 1:2(1) ack 9 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 74855531 837321186>
11:00:03.744740 IP 172.16.30.1.58043 > 172.16.30.139.postgres: . ack 2 win 65535 <nop,nop,timestamp 837321190 74855531>
11:00:03.744816 IP 172.16.30.1.58043 > 172.16.30.139.postgres: P 9:88(79) ack 2 win 65535 <nop,nop,timestamp 837321190 74855531>
11:00:03.746083 IP 172.16.30.139.postgres > 172.16.30.1.58043: P 2:148(146) ack 88 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 74855533 837321190>
11:00:03.746318 IP 172.16.30.1.58043 > 172.16.30.139.postgres: . ack 148 win 65535 <nop,nop,timestamp 837321191 74855533>
11:00:03.749231 IP 172.16.30.139.postgres > 172.16.30.1.58043: F 148:148(0) ack 88 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 74855536 837321191>
11:00:03.749471 IP 172.16.30.1.58043 > 172.16.30.139.postgres: . ack 149 win 65535 <nop,nop,timestamp 837321194 74855536>
```

Answer (score 3):

`192.168.2.109` may be your mac's address on your internal network, but `172.16.30.1` is the mac's address on the virtual network that it uses to communicate with the VM, and that's the address you need to configure in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: @mlevit This is exactly right (in fact if you run `ifconfig` on your Mac you will even see a (virtual) interface with the IP `172.16.30.1`, which is created by your VM software...).